# LDAP integration in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, ldap

I'm new to symfony & LDAP. Is there any step by step tutorial or videos to integrate LDAP in symfony2?

Comment: This implementation for ldapm only need lib php-ldap. https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know any tutorial or video about LDAP in Symfony2 but here are 2 bundles I used in many projects:

- [`OpenSkyLdapBundle`](https://github.com/opensky/LdapBundle/blob/master/README.md) (requires ZF2 LDAP component)
- [`FR3DLdapBundle`](https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) (integration with `FOSUserBundle`)

Comment: I have used FOSUSer with FR3D ldap Bundle. Now the problem is                    MappingException: No mapping file found named 'Acme.UserBundle.Entity.User.php' for class 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User'.          I'm getting this error

Comment: Do you have a custom autoloader?

Comment: no, I have to know what should I give in "fos_user:
    db_driver:" in config.yml Please advice

Comment: Another one solution is out: [Daps](https://github.com/relwell/DapsBundle). It works with Synfony 2.1 and author will make it out with 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Symfony2 should have LDAP support already in there. If you are constrained to an older version, consider using [DapsBundle](https://github.com/relwell/DapsBundle), since its functionality is patterned after Symfony2's upgrade path, meaning it should be easier for you when you do upgrade your Symfony2 version.. You can learn more about on my blog at http://robertelwell.info/blog/daps-ldap-symfony2/.

Answer (score 0):

FOSUserBundle is a bundle for authenticate users against a DB, if you don't want manager your users with the DB then you must do a little customizations for break the dependency in FR3DLdapBundle.

Writing your own UserManager and setting it in the configuration should be enough.

The UserManager is used for create the User instance the first time.