# Symfony2 - how to get apache's current LDAP user in symfony?

Tags: apache, symfony, ldap

i have  configured my apache vhost as follows:

- i have a LocationMatch with diffrent Url, where i have a ldap authentication.

when I open one of these url in the browser,I get the login window from apache and i can login successfully

if I am logged in successfully I get the remote user from apache.
My question is where can I catch this remote user in symfony,to make the authorization.

Is there a possibility to configure this in the security.yml? 
has anyone a suggestion how I could proceed?

Comment: So basically you want to get apache's current LDAP user in your application?

Comment: yes I want to intercept the apacheuser with symfony. 
I have a working ldap webservice, so I just need the user to load the groups

Answer (score 0):

There are several **bundles** around providing **LDAP** integration for symfony.

including but not limited to:

- [OpenSky/LDAPBundle](https://github.com/opensky/LdapBundle/blob/master/README.md)
- [Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle](https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)
- [relwell/DapsBundle](https://github.com/relwell/DapsBundle)
- ...

More information can be found here:

- [LDAP integration in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877695/ldap-integration-in-symfony2)
- http://robertelwell.info/blog/daps-ldap-symfony2/
- ...

There might be native LDAP support in Symfony sometime soon, if **[this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/5189/files)** gets merged.